# How to remove all li from ul?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 5 items in the list. I want remove all of them.

**View**

```
<ul class="cg-tag-list" >
    <li ng-repeat="tag in list">
       <span>{{tag}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
angular.forEach($scope.list, function (item) {
   // Put your code here             
});
```

Comment: Remove from `object` or `context` ?

Comment: @Vineet: Please elaborate what is object or context here?

Comment: Do you want to delete from object in controller or just want to hide the `li` in HTML ?

Comment: I want remove all li which is exists in ul?

Comment: Are you looking for CSS `ul li { display: none; }`?

Comment: @ManojKumar no only with angular

Comment: `$scope.list = [];` will empty that array out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, you want to remove html element. So, first define selector to html element i.e, `<li class="tagClass" ng-repeat="tag in list">` and then working with **tagClass** in JS file.

**JS**

```
 angular.forEach(angular.element('.tagClass'),function(value,key){
        var data = angular.element(value);
         data.remove();
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

> Adding and removing list items with AngularJS

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5dn2mtb8/406/)

HTML code:

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <ul ng-controller="ItemsController" class="nav">
        <input type="text" value="ItemName" ng-model="newItemName"
        placeholder="name of new item...">
            <button ng-click="addItem()">Add Me</button>
             <button ng-click="rem()">Remove all</button>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items.data" id="item{{item.id}}">
            <a href="#">{{item.title}}</a>  <a ng-click="deleteItem($index)" class="delete-item">x</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ADDING item:

```
$scope.addItem = function (index) {
        items.data.push({
            id: $scope.items.data.length + 1,
            title: $scope.newItemName
        });
    }
```

Removing item:

```
  $scope.deleteItem = function (index) {
        items.data.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

Removing all item:

```
$scope.rem = function (index) {
  $scope.items=[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can empty the list as `$scope.list = [];` or if you don't want list to be empty and make that particulate `li` invisible you can add one attribute to list item as `isVisible` and use `ng-show` directive as:

```
 $scope.list = [{isVisible:true,value:"sample"},{isVisible:false,value:"sample"},{isVisible:true,value:"sample"}]

<li ng-repeat="tag in list" ng-show="tag.isVisible">
       <span>{{tag.value}}</span>
</li>
```